# How to detect file permissions when extracting tar file?

Tags: java, compression, apache-commons

When using [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) to extract a tar file, how do I find out the file permissions (read, write, executable) of each [TarArchiveEntry](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/tar/TarArchiveEntry.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TarArchiveEntry provides a method "getMode()" which returns the Unix file mode, e.g.

```
TarArchiveEntry entry = input.getNextTarEntry();
while(entry != null) {
    System.out.println("Entry: " + entry.getName() + ", Mode: " + entry.getMode());
    entry = input.getNextTarEntry();
}
```

with a test-tar-file it will result in:

```
Entry: usr/local/bin/bcdiff, Mode: 493
Entry: usr/local/bin/jgrep, Mode: 493
Entry: usr/local/bin/ysh, Mode: 365
```

which translates to:

```
-rwxr-xr-x bcdiff
-rwxr-xr-x jgrep
-r-xr-xr-x ysh
```

You can read up on details about the mode numbers on many sites in the Internet, e.g. [here](http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/19060-unix-file-permissions.html)

HTH... Dominik.

Comment: Is there any pre-rolled way to take that "493" and set the untar'd file's permissions to match?